# Vue props data not updating in child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

Hi everyone I just want some explanation about vue props data. So I'm passing value from parent component to child component. The thing is when parent data has data changes/update it's not updating in child component.

```
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: '<div class="child">{{val}}</div>',
  props: ['testData'],
  data: function () {
    return {
        val: this.testData
    }
  }
});
```

But using the props name ***{{testdata}}*** it's displaying the data from parent properly

```
Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: '<div class="child">{{testData}}</div>',
  props: ['testData'],
  data: function () {
    return {
        val: this.testData
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance

Fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/PenAndPapers/waqb81fy/17/)

Comment: You're creating a **copy** in `val: this.testData`. This is pretty much down to JS references.

Comment: See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: thanks @Phil, but does val wont update when values changes

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Comment: @Phil, not a question really I just want some explanation, thanks

Comment: The data function is called *once* in the component lifetime, which means that val is set when the component is created. There is nothing that automatically updates `val` in your code. You likely want `val` to be a computed property, or just render the prop. Or you would watch `testData` and update `val` when a change occurs.

Comment: Thanks @Bert, I've tried computed property and it works as I expected

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is best explained with a very simple example

```js
let a = 'foo'
let b = a
a = 'bar'

console.info('a', a)
console.info('b', b)
```

When you assign...

```
val: this.testData
```

you're setting the **initial value** of `val` once when the component is created. Changes to the prop will not be reflected in `val` in the same way that changes to `a` above are not reflected in `b`.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: this doesn't answer the question of how to make the props dynamic.

Comment: @grantzukowski that's not what OP was asking. This answers the question asked. In fact, I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: He was asking how to make the passed in prop value dynamic, so if it changes, the child reacts.

Comment: @grantzukowski no _"he"_ is not. I suggest you read the question and the comments on the question again. OP's question makes it quite clear that they're able to see changes to the passed in prop values (see second snippet)

Comment: Its literally exactly what I said. I suggest you read the question again. In this case, I think the prop needs to be passed in as a computed value and there needs to be a watcher in the child. Explaining the concept is not answering the question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50035675/dom-is-not-updating-when-props-value-changes-in-vuejs

Comment: @grantzukowski are you kidding me? OP literally says [_"@Phil, not a question really I just want some explanation, thanks"_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419314/vue-props-data-not-updating-in-child-component/49419399?noredirect=1#comment85840216_49419314). They want to know **why**, using the first snippet, changes to the parent data are not reflected in the child

Answer (score 0):

I resolve with! `this.$set(this.mesas, i, event);`

```js
data() {
    return { mesas: [] }
},
components: {
    'table-item': table_l,    
},
methods: {
    deleteMesa: function(event) {
        let i = this.mesas.map(item => item.id).indexOf(event.id);
        console.log("mesa a borrare", i); 
        this.mesas.splice(i, 1);
    },
    updateMesa: function(event) {
        let i =this.mesas.map(item => item.id).indexOf(event.id);
        console.log("mesa a actualizar", i); 
        ///    With this method Vue say Warn
        //this.mesas[i]=event;  
        /// i Resolve as follow
        this.$set(this.mesas, i, event);
     },
     // Adds Useres online
     addMesa: function(me) {
         console.log(me);
         this.mesas.push(me);
     }
}
```