# DOM is not updating when props value changes in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent and a child. In the parent am passing 3 variables as props to the child. In the Child I am using the **watch()** to look for varaible changes. When the child is created for the 1st time the **watch** works as expected but when the data from the props in updated then DOM of the child is not updated. The watch function which is looking for data change of the variable is not running at all.

Here is my code. Its a bit lengthy so please bear with it.

***Parentcomponent.vue***

```
 <template>
 <div>


 <button type="button" v-on:click="LoadCatalog()">Click me!! </button>

 <div v-if="displayCategoryList" class="row">
    <h3>Select Category Men</h3>
    <select v-model="menCategory" v-on:change="passDataToChild()">
        <option v-for="item in categoriesfordisplay.men"  v-bind:key="item">
            {{ item }}
        </option>
    </select> 
    <h3>Select Category Women</h3>
    <select v-model="WomenCategory" v-on:change="passDataToChild()">
        <option v-for="item in categoriesfordisplay.women" v-bind:key="item">
            {{ item }}
        </option>
    </select> 
 </div>

 <div v-if="displayData" class="row">

        <div v-for="item in data_to_show_on_mainpage"  v-bind:key="item" >
            <button v-on:click="newfunction(item.cat,item.gender)" >
                <img v-bind:src="item.data.image"> </img>
                <p >{{ item.cat }}</p>
            </button>
         </div>



 </div>

 <category-items v-if="displayCategoryData" v-bind:gender="gender" v-bind:catsgory="catsgory" v-bind:catlog="catlog" ></category-items>





 </div>
 </template>


<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  import CategoryItems from './CategoryItems'
   export default {
   name:  'GetCategoryItemsAndDisplayOne',
   props: ['categoriesfordisplay','ismainpage', 'catalogselected'],

components:{
    CategoryItems,
    },
    data(){
    return {
        IsMainPage_1 : "",
        data_to_show_on_mainpage : [],
        cat :[],
        displayData : true,
        menCategory : "",
        WomenCategory : "",
        displayCategoryList: true,
        displayCategoryData : false,
        CategoryFromImage : "",
        //dataSentToChild : {}
        gender : "",
        catsgory : "",
        catlog : ""


    }
  },
     methods:{
    passDataToChild(){
        if(this.menCategory != ""){

            this.catsgory = this.menCategory
            this.gender = "men"
            this.catlog = this.catalogselected
            this.menCategory = "" 

        }else if(this.WomenCategory != ""){
            this.catsgory = this.WomenCategory
            this.gender = "women"
            this.catlog = this.catalogselected
            this.WomenCategory = ""
        } 
        this.displayData = false
        this.displayCategoryData = true
    },
    changevalue(){
        this.data_to_show_on_mainpage = []
    },
    CatlogService(catlog_name,category,gender,mainpage){


        let url = "http://localhost:5000/xyz/" + (this.catalogselected).replace(/'/g,"%27") +"/api/"+ (gender) + "/catalogvis/" + (category) +"/items"

        axios.get(encodeURI(url)).then((resp)=>{
            var jsonData = {"data": resp.data.response.Results.results[0] , "cat": category , "gender" : gender}
            )
            this.data_to_show_on_mainpage.push(jsonData)

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("we got an error the url is " + url)
            console.log(err);
        })
    },

    GetItemsToShowonMainPage(){
        this.changevalue()


        if(this.categoriesfordisplay.men_for_display.length>0){
            for(let i =0;i<this.categoriesfordisplay.men_for_display.length;i++){
                let category = this.categoriesfordisplay.men_for_display[i].replace(/"/g,"%27");
                console.log(category)
                this.CatlogService(this.catalogselected,category,'men',this.ismainpage)
            }

        }
        if(this.categoriesfordisplay.women_for_display.length>0){

            for(let i = 0;i<this.categoriesfordisplay.women_for_display.length;i++){
                let category = this.categoriesfordisplay.women_for_display[i].replace(/"/g,"");

                this.CatlogService(this.catalogselected,category,'women',this.ismainpage)
            }

        }
    },
    LoadCatalog(){
        this.displayCategoryData = false
        this.GetItemsToShowonMainPage()
        this.displayData = true
        this.displayCategoryList = true

    },
    newfunction(Cats,gender){
        this.displayCategoryData = true
        this.displayData = false
        this.catsgory = Cats
        this.gender = gender
        this.catlog = this.catalogselected
    }



},
created(){

    this.GetItemsToShowonMainPage()
}



}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

The ***Child component CategoryItems.vue*** is below

```
<template>

<div>
    <h4>{{ genders }}</h4>
    <h4>{{ category }}</h4>
    <h4>{{ catalogue }}</h4>
</div>
</template>


<script>


export default{
name : 'CategoryItems',
props : ['gender','catsgory','catlog'],



data(){
    return {
        genders : "",
        category : "",
        catalogue : "",

    }
},
watch : {
    category : function(){

        this.GetProducts()
    }
},
methods:{
    GetProducts(){
    this.genders = this.gender
    this.category = this.catsgory
    this.catalogue = this.catlog

    }
},
created(){
    this.genders = this.gender
    this.category = this.catsgory
    this.catalogue = this.catlog


 }

 }
 </script>


 <style>
 </style>
```

As You can see whenever the ***category*** variable in the child changes the function **GetProducts** should run but it is not happening.
It is executed only when the  child component is created.

Where I am going wrong with my logic.
Thanks

Comment: the name of the prop is catsgory.
props : ['gender','catsgory','catlog'],

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are only setting the child component's variable in the `created` hook, therefor they are not reactive.

The best way is to make a reactive data based on the prop is to create a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) based on that property :

```
computed: {
  category: function() {
    return this.catsgory;
  },
},
```

This computed will be automatically updated whenever the props changes.

You also can watch the prop directly, and force the watcher to trigger immediately (take a look at the [the API](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch)).

Your child component's watcher will look like this :

```
watch : {
  category: {
    handler: function() {
        this.GetProducts();
    },
    immediate: true,
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I have 2 questions

Q1-
You said that setting child component's variable in the created hook doesnot make them reactive. So what is the ideal way make them reactive so I dont face this problem in future.

Q2-
In my child component is it a good way to intialize data like this data(){
    return {
        genders : this.gender,
        category : this.catsgory,
        catalogue : this.catlog

    }
},

Comment: Q1 : You should make a computed property based on the prop, or directly use the prop (remember that you should not be modifying props directly). Q2 : No, cf Q1. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: https://codepen.io/handsomer223/pen/BxLjej

I have tried to achieve the same result using the computed property.
I am doing it the right way.

Comment: This computed property does absolutely nothing. Props **are** reactive, you don't need to _wrap_ them in a computed property

Answer (score 2):

In my case, If initial props value(array) is `undefind`, even if props change, render was not fired.

So I changed inital props value to empty array `[]`

Then problem solved.